# Pipelight unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, pipelight

I installed Trusty Tahr on my old Dell Studio 1537 a few hours ago. Since then I've been trying to install [pipelight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ5wI.jpg) and failed miserably. I get the unmet dependencies problem as many people have before me. I've tried several suggestions that I've found both here and in other forums.

```
# Clean + -f install #
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
# Output: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
```

I've also tried removing the repository and adding it again with no luck. I tried purging the repository then adding it again as suggested by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) post and now terminal won't even find the package, much less try to install. I also tried installing aptitude as I've [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) that it may be able to install packages somewhat forcibly (also failed, because I also get unmet dependencies when trying to install aptitude). Lastly I also get unmet dependencies when trying to install [gimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4jkU.jpg), which leads me to believe it might be a system problem instead of a package/dependency problem, so I went so far as to re-install the system from scratch with no luck. So far the only things I managed to install in the system are the firmware-b43-installer for the wireless (Broadcom BCM4312) card and ubuntu-restricted-extras.

So now, I'm looking for solutions that I haven't tried yet or something I might have missed. Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to increase the chances of a helpful answer, please provide the 2 most important missing parts in the question: 1) What exact command was typed at first, and 2) What error message was seen (e.g. _what_ unmet dependencies did you get?) expressions like "failed miserably" and "no luck" are not helpful and not a substitute for the actual facts. Similarly for "add the repository" (which one?)  etc.

Comment: After OS installation I installed the broadcom driver (sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer) and restricted extras (sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras). Then I tried installing pipelight, with "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable", and "sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi". I also tried using the command available at the pipelight main page "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi". All attempts resulted in the error in first the link 'pipelight'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but I re-installed the system one more time and third time was the charm. Pipelight installed this time. I still don't know why it didn't install before, but the problem got solved anyway, so thanks to everyone who at least took a look at this question. And thanks to arielf for trying to help me make clearer questions, I'll try to improve on that next time :)

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself.  That's the best way to learn.  I suspect what happened here may have been the order of commands.  For a totally new repo, (like `ppa:pipelight/stable` above), the repository needs to be added first, then an `apt-get update` is needed to update the index of packages, latest versions available, etc. Finally `apt-get install <package_name>` needs to be issued for the actual install.  Adding new repositories is a relatively rare operation (and needs to be done only once per repo).